# JavaScript regex matching character it shouldn't match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that checks for characters not in the character class:

```
[^\w+\-:\.\(\)\"\*\?\&\|\!\{\}\[\]\^~\\@\#\/\$\%\'\= ]
```

I'm expecting that it doesn't match the dash '-' on the following string, however it is:

```
SEPCO−SEPA50PT−S−TFA−ALC18−PZ4
```

Comment: What's with all those slashes?

Comment: Most of those backslashes are not needed. You only need to escape meta-characters,

Comment: And most meta-characters lose their special meaning inside `[]`.

Comment: Those are special characters I'm escaping. They are checking for literals. For example, \? checks for ?.

Comment: @MusicalShore `?` is not special inside `[]`.

Comment: It does contain a dash.

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html .

Comment: I used regex101.com to check the regex, it said "*?&|!{} a single character in the list *?&|!{} literally (case sensitive)". I took that to mean that all those characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `−` in this:

> SEPCO−SEPA50PT−S−TFA−ALC18−PZ4

is not the same character as the `-` in your regex.  It is in fact the Unicode MINUS-SIGN rather than the Unicode HYPHEN-MINUS.

Here are the two next to each other showing they're different:

> −
>
> -

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: @MusicalShore: What do you mean? You add that character to your character class.

Comment: As @Felix says, just add that character to the rest of the ones you want to exclude.  JavaScript supports unicode in source files, so you can just paste it straight in.

Comment: I have '\-' in my character class. It shouldn't match it, I'm looking for characters that are not in my character class in order to fail the test.

Comment: It is a different `-`.  Like if you type a - in Word etc and press space, it will convert it to a longer one - as far as the regex is concerned, it's an entirely different character.

Comment: @MusicalShore Edited my answer to put the two next to each other to more clearly show it.

Comment: @MusicalShore: *"I have '\-' in my character class. It shouldn't match it,"* I find the answer pretty clear: The "dash-like looking" character you have in your expression **is not the same character** that is used in the text. Lets have a look at a simpler example: `[^a]` will match the text `b` because `b` is not in the character class.

Comment: That's odd. I only have one of those characters on my keyboard. To be clear, the MINUS-SIGN is in my string and the HYPHEN-MINUS is in my character class?

Comment: Yes.  I also only have `-` on my keyboard.  I don't have é on my keyboard either, but it's still a character.

Comment: @MusicalShore: You probably also don't have `ü` or `ö` on your keyboard. But those characters still exist and can appear in text.

Comment: Right, but how would a user have entered that character easily w/o doing some key combo voodoo?

Comment: Who knows - that's an entirely different question.  What software are they using etc?  You need to ask them, not us.  The fact is, the character is there.  As I mentioned further up, if you type a - in in the middle of a sentence in Word/Outlook etc, it gets turned into yet another dash (– EN DASH).  Still looks the same, but yet _another different character_.  Is it perhaps auto generated from somewhere?  I find it hard to believe that users would be typing in a code like that?